# SQL:- I am trying to fetch the rows in a table where maximum of 3 rows should have amount <=1024

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my table

```
   sender     | recipient  | date       | amount
  ------------+------------+------------+--------
   Smith      | Williams   | 2000-01-01 | 200
   Smith      | Taylor     | 2002-09-27 | 1024
   Smith      | Johnson    | 2005-06-26 | 512
   Williams   | Johnson    | 2010-12-17 | 100
   Williams   | Johnson    | 2004-03-22 | 10
   Brown      | Johnson    | 2013-03-20 | 500
   Johnson    | Williams   | 2007-06-02 | 400
   Johnson    | Williams   | 2005-06-26 | 400
   Johnson    | Williams   | 2005-06-26 | 200
```

A query should return just taylor and Johnson

because taylor has 1024 in one row while johnson gets them in 3 rows (512, 100, 500 = 1112) but not williams because it takes four rows to get above 1024

I tried this query:

```
select   
    q1.r, q1.sum1, q1.c 
from
    (select  
         recipient as r, count(*) as c, sum(amount) as sum1
     from 
         transfers 
     group by 
         recipient) as q1
where 
    c <= 3 AND sum1 <= 1024
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: am sorry am just starting with quering..its for postgresql

Comment: Title says you want > 1024 but your sql says AND sum1 <= 1024 also title says count min is three but sql says count max is 3.  Which is it?

Comment: oh sorry it is <=1024

Comment: and max rows is 3 or min rows is three? c <= 3 AND sum1 <= 1024 indicates you want max 3 rows, title still says min three rows

Comment: max row has to be 3, updated again. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: row 1: got ('Taylor', '1024', '1'), expected 'Johnson') . it fetches just one row taylor

Answer (score 2):

You can get the TOP 3 amounts for each `recipient` and then use `SUM` and `HAVING`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY recipient ORDER BY amount DESC) AS rn
    FROM transfers
)
SELECT recipient
FROM Cte
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY recipient
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 1024
```

Comment: Sorry I just updated that the sum has to be less than 1024 and it still doesnt seem to be fetching the right output though I had given <=1024

Comment: @Ashvitha your current query seems fine? What's wrong with it?

Comment: row 1: got ('Taylor', '1024', '1'), expected 'Johnson')

Comment: ecpecting johnson and taylor

Answer (score 1):

Using Postgresql's LATERAL join feature:

```
select a.recipient,sum(c.amount) totamount from
    (select distinct recipient from testtable ) a 
  left join lateral 
    (select amount from testtable where recipient=a.recipient 
     order by amount desc limit 3) c 
  on true group by a.recipient having sum(c.amount) >= 1024 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this window functions and aggregation.

```
Select recipient
From (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by recipient order by amount desc) as seqnum
      From t
     ) t
Where seqnum <= 3
Group by recipient
Having sum(amount) > 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns don't match yours exactly but this should get you what you want

```
select * from (
select name, 
sum(amount) as total, 
count(*) as rec_count
from transfers 
group by name 
having count(*) <= 3) tbl
where total >= 1024
```